# Continous aggregate not covering entire time interval

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, materialized-views, timescaledb

I created a continuous aggregate with time bucket as 5 mins. While adding policy I gave policy as below:

```
SELECT add_continuous_aggregate_policy('public.test_five_min_view',
                                  start_offset => INTERVAL '1 hour',
                                  end_offset => INTERVAL '0 minute',
                                  schedule_interval => INTERVAL '1 hour');
```

On checking logs I found that it is by default skipping 5 mins.

```
2023-08-03 12:12:50.924 UTC [2771] LOG:  refreshing continuous aggregate "test_five_min_view" in window [ 2023-08-03 11:15:00+00, 2023-08-03 12:10:00+00 ]
```

The expectation was that it will start at 11:10:00 to 12:10:00, which is not the case now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start_offset`: the start of the refresh window relative to when the policy runs

`end_offset`: the end of the refresh window relative to when the policy runs

Both are relative to policy run time. In your case policy ran at `2023-08-03 12:12:50.924`. To avoid the gaps in aggregate, choose `start_offset` larger than `schedule_interval` (consider your project historic data filling) and timescale does aggregations only for the buckets where there is a data change.

Comment: Document on continuous aggregate covers this scenario: https://github.com/timescale/docs.timescale.com-content/blob/master/using-timescaledb/continuous-aggregates.md